# Does two-ninths month NSF rule apply to non-tenure track research assistant professor positions?

Tags: research-process, funding, assistant-professor, nsf

I wonder if the NSF two-ninths months rule applies to Research Assistant Professor positions? This is a non-tenure track position, however I may submit a sole-PI grant and I wonder if I can cover 100% of my salary using NSF grant.